# Ember.js helper with moment.js (using ember-cli) : Handlebars error: Could not find property

Tags: ember.js, momentjs

I'm trying to use moment.js in my ember.js app (built with ember-cli), I have a trouble with this error

`Handlebars error: Could not find property 'formatDate' on object`

I think it's same as this error [How to use Custom helpers in ember-app-kit?](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-to-use-custom-helpers-in-ember-app-kit/3336) but I already did the same approach but not working yet. Anyone got same error? Please help me to figure out.

I put 
`app.import('vendor/momentjs/moment.js');` in `Brocfile.js` 
and 
`"moment": true` in `.jshintrc` as in ember-cli documentation,
and I used the helper `{{formatDate date}}` in `PostsTemplate`

I created a helper `app/helpers/formatDate.js`

```
var formatDate = Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(function(date) {
  return moment(date).fromNow();
});

export default formatDate;
```

I also tried this syntax in `app/helpers/formatDate.js`, but neither works and both get same error

```
export default Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('formatDate',function(date) {
  return moment(date).fromNow();
});
```

Comment: well, it's definitely not finding the helper, is broccoli not including it in the build?

Comment: @kingpin2k it's already included when I installed ember-cli in package.json `"broccoli-ember-hbs-template-compiler": "^1.5.0",` this one right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think your file name 'formatDate.js' has the wrong format. Try 'format-date.js' and it should work.

Excerpt from http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/:

> Handlebars helpers will only be found automatically by the resolver if their **name contains a dash** (reverse-word, translate-text, etc.) This is the result of a choice that was made in Ember, to help both disambiguate properties from helpers, and to mitigate the performance hit of helper resolution for all bindings.

Use your new 'format-date' helper like this:

```
{{format-date "29/05/2014"}}
```

Comment: thank you! it was my careless mistake, but glad that it now works!

Comment: I'm getting 'moment is not defined error'. any solutions?

Comment: @kushdilip did you include the 'moment.js' library in Brocfile.js and bower.js?

Comment: yes, it is working after `ember build`.
Can you please look into this question [how to deploy ember-cli to gh-pages](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24404080/877492)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this symptom as well and had a different solution.

I had a helper in app/helpers/fh.js called 'fh' in order to be able to use it I needed to add it to the controller as follows

```
import fh from '../helpers/fh';
```

If I didn't have the import line I would get the following error:

"Handlebars error: Could not find property 'fh' on object"