# How do I deploy Ember.js app developed with ember-cli on github pages?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, github-pages

I have successfully created a small application using ember-cli. I tried pushing it to gh-pages branch of my github repo but it shows error in browser console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

loading of vendor.js and vendor.js files from `dist/assets` is also failing.

I'm not able to run standalone ember app from `dist` folder in local machine as well, same errors.

has anyone tried it. if yes how to do it correctly?

Comment: What do u get in the console? Might be an issue with the base url. http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/#deployments

Comment: test it yourself [expense app](http://kushdilip.github.io/Bounty-Web-Expenses/dist/)

Comment: I think you need to push the contents inside 'dist' folder to the gh-pages branch (Under the hood its jekyl). I dont think you can serve from `dist`.

Comment: if that is the case then it should work straight from dist folder in local machine, right? but it's not.

Comment: Try changing the 'baseURL' inside config/environment.js to your localhost path. Like baseURL: '/Bounty-Web-Expenses/dist'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since December 2014 there is also an [ember-cli addon for this](https://github.com/poetic/ember-cli-github-pages).

First make sure to have set `modulePrefix` in `config/environment.js` to your repo's name on github.  E.g., for https://github.com/username/my-cool-repo it should be `modulePrefix: 'my-cool-repo'`.

Then follow these instructions:

1. Install the addon.
   `$ ember install:addon ember-cli-github-pages`
2. Commit the changes made by the addon.
   `$ git add . && git commit -m "Installed addon ember-cli-github-pages"`
3. Create the `gh-pages` branch with only the necessary files.
   `` $ git checkout --orphan gh-pages && rm -rf `ls -a | grep -vE '.gitignore|.git|node_modules|bower_components|\.\/|\.\.\/'` && git add . && git commit -m "Initial gh-pages commit" ``
4. Switch back to your source branch (most likely `master`).
   `$ git checkout master`
5. Build your ember app to the `gh-pages` branch.
   `$ ember gh-pages:commit --message "Initial gh-pages release"`
6. Push everything (or at least the `gh-pages` branch) to github.

*(This was different for ember-cli <= 0.1.4 and might change again in the future. Make sure to visit the [addon's readme](https://github.com/poetic/ember-cli-github-pages).)*

Comment: I'll try this. I recently started using ember-cli.

Comment: I tested the addon partially. but the addon doesn't do much. I am still not able to run the organization page using ember.. eg. say kushdilip.github.io.

And even this repo page runs from https://yourUsername.github.io/myEmberApplication/dist

Answer (score 2):

As the comments already say: change the `baseUrl` in `config/environment.js` to the name of the GitHub repository you are pushing the app to. For example:

Your GitHub respository is called `myEmberApplication` and resides in

`https://github.com/yourUsername/myEmberApplication.git`

then the URL to this project's gh-pages would be

`https://yourUsername.github.io/myEmberApplication`

So in your case you have to change the `baseUrl` from `/` (default) to `/myEmberApplication`.

The reason why you have to do this is because ember-cli adds the `<base>` header to your `index.html` file.