# How to deploy ember-cli app onto nginx

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've been trying to deploy my ember-cli app in production mode onto an nginx server.  I've reviewed the ember-cli docs and looked at other similar questions such as ([How do I deploy Ember.js app developed with ember-cli on github pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24404080/how-do-i-deploy-ember-js-app-developed-with-ember-cli-on-github-pages)) - these seem to suggest that setting the ENV.baseURL variable in /app/config/environment.js should address issues but I can't find a value that works for me.

The files generated by `ember build --environment production` are at /Users/gordon/src/app/dist

The nginx config looks like:

```
server {
   listen       4200 ssl;
   server_name  localhost;

   ssl_certificate      /Users/gordon/src/app/server.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key  /Users/gordon/src/app/server.key;

   ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
   ssl_session_timeout  5m;

   ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
   root /Users/gordon/src/app/dist/;

   location / {
       # index  index.html;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?/$request_uri;

   }
}
```

In Users/gordon/src/app/config/environment.js if I leave ENV.baseURL at the default I get shown the following errors in my browser console ...

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function vendor-70567c507a348c9884b7aba3ccaae1fd.js:14
Uncaught ReferenceError: DS is not defined
```

... if I set it to /Users/gordon/src/app/, /Users/gordon/src/app/dist/ or /Users/gordon/src/app/dist I get

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :4200/Users/gordon/src/sellthru/dist/assets/vendor-70567c507a348c9884b7aba3ccaae1fd.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :4200/Users/gordon/src/sellthru/dist/assets/sellthru-app-4b7e6077c7df38b31e70e32056d7d7aa.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I'm sure I'm probably missing something simple but can't for the life of me figure it out...  If anyone is able to put me out of my misery I'd appreciate it ;-)

Comment: What's the output of `ember --version`? Are you able to deploy an development build to your nginx server?

Comment: @oliver The version output is as follows and yes I'm able to deploy development builds without problems    version: 0.0.40
    node: 0.10.30
    npm: 1.4.21

Comment: That's odd... I would say leave ENV.baseURL at the default '/' because nginx serves '/' your dist directory. `DS is not defined` looks like you have forgotton to `import DS from 'ember-data'` in one of your models. But this error should also occur in dev builds.

Comment: Hmm - I've checked my models and they all import DS. Is there perhaps somewhere else that I should import it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jamie White we tracked down the issue to the ember-cli-bootstrap addon. I've removed that and manually added bootstrap now and all is sweetness and light.  See also https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/1727

Comment: Hi, could you please tell me how to add ember-cli-bootstrap manually?