# Error in deploying ember app on gh-pages by Travis

Tags: git, bash, ember.js, github-pages

I want to deploy my front-end made in ember js on gh-pages after successful Travis Build.  But when Travis runs it gives error as follows :

```
after_success

$ bash ./script/gh_deploy.sh
cleaning up
cleaning up...
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://ParthS007:undefined@github.com     /fossasia/badgeyay/'
Error: git push https://ParthS007:undefined@github.com/fossasia/badgeyay          gh-pages exited with nonzero status
Error: git push https://ParthS007:undefined@github.com/fossasia/badgeyay gh-pages exited with nonzero status
 at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/travis/build/fossasia/badgeyay/frontend  /node_modules/ember-cli-deploy-git/lib/run.js:19:19)
 at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
 at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
 at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
 at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:230:5)   Pipeline aborted`

Done. Your build exited with 0.
```

This is the link to files which I have changed in my Pull request for gh-pages deployment https://github.com/fossasia/badgeyay/pull/529/files
Please suggest what should be changed for successful gh-pages deployment.

Comment: @Cyrus Is it correct now?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/28280719/6156142 
As he told in the answer below, you got a beautiful package who will do the trick for you

But your problem seems to came from authentification. 
 You may have to precise github login since travis doesn't know it and doesn't have the permissions to do it for you.
You can find what your looking in Github profile `settings > Developer settings > Personal access token`